# PostgreSQL CASE expression

Tags: postgresql, case

how to write a case expression with Postgres?  I have this

```
case
  when rc.stat = 0 Then unpaid
  when rc.stat = 1 Then paid
  when rc.stat = 2 Then dispute
  else rc.stat
end
```

but when I go to run the statement I get an error of

```
Error: column "unpaid" does not exist
```

I have also tried double quotes and brackets around the text values, but all of those options give me errors.  Just to note, the values unpaid, paid, dispute are **NOT** fields in the database, but text values I want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) there, e.g. `'unpaid'`.

Because all branches of a CASE expression must return the same data type, you will also need to cast the `stat` column to `text` as well (assuming it's some kind of number as you compare it to one)

```
case
  when rc.stat = 0 Then 'unpaid'
  when rc.stat = 1 Then 'paid'
  when rc.stat = 2 Then 'dispute'
  else rc.stat::text
end
```

As you only use `=` as the comparison operator, you can simplify that expression to:

```
case rc.stat
  when 0 Then 'unpaid'
  when 1 Then 'paid'
  when 2 Then 'dispute'
  else rc.stat::text
end
```

Comment: Ohhh, so the issue was I was trying to write text values to an int field - but casting the field to a text field resolves :)

Comment: @TimmyTurner: your original issue was that you didn't write your string constants with single quotes.